# How to create a force.com project in a SSO sandbox

Tags: single-sign-on, eclipse, ide, force.com-ide

Recently, we enabled Single Sign On in one of our sandbox.

When I try to refresh metadata using Eclipse, I am getting following error.

[image]

I have tried by specifying different environment which matches to new org URL, but it didn't work.

Are there any different configuration steps needs to be performed?